# React useState and onSubmit form doesn't update the state immediately - validation best practice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm developing a custom Form validation for my React project with Typescript.
I'm facing an issue with the useState that is not updating immediately the state containing the errors when I submit a form.
Let me provide you an example.

```
const initialFormState = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
}

const SignUpForm = () => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialFormState);
  const [validationErrors, setValidationErrors] = useState<string>([]);

  const handleChange = () => {
    // handle the change implementation updating the formValues ...
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    doValidationOnSubmit();

    if (validationErrors.length > 0) {
      console.log('validation errors!!');
      return;
    }

    doLogin();
  };

  const doValidationOnSubmit = () => {
    Object.entries(formValues).forEach(([inputName, value]) => {
      if (formValues[inputName] === '') {
        setValidationErrors((oldValidationErrors) => [...oldValidationErrors, `${inputName} is not valid`]);
      }
    });
  }

  const doLogin = () => {
    // do login logic
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="email" name="email" onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type="password" name="email" onChange={handleChange} />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default SignUpForm;
```

When I'm checking for the errors in the `handleSubmit`, there are no errors, even if errors should be present there:

```
if (validationErrors.length > 0) {
      console.log('validation errors!!');
      return;
    }
```

In general, I'm wondering what is the best practice in order to avoid these kinds of issues with the react state not updating immediately the state?
I already tried with `useEffect`, listening on the `validationErrors` changes but nothing changes actually, the behavior is pretty the same.
I'm sure I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

`useState` is asynchronous, so state changes (`setValidationErrors`) are not applied immediately. Therefore, you cannot get the latest state of `validationErrors` in the next line.

We can do validation and set state separately. In that case, you can leverage the latest value (not the latest state) to check values validity.

```
const initialFormState = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
}

const SignUpForm = () => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialFormState);
  const [validationErrors, setValidationErrors] = useState<string>([]);

  const handleChange = () => {
    // handle the change implementation updating the formValues ...
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    //get all invalid values
    const invalidValues = returnInvalidValues();
 
    //update state
    setValidationErrors(prev => [...prev, ...invalidValues])

    if (invalidValues.length > 0) {
      console.log('validation errors!!');
      return;
    }

    doLogin();
  };

  const returnInvalidValues = () => {
    return Object.entries(formValues).filter(([inputName, value]) => formValues[inputName] === ''). map(invalidValue => `${inputName} is not valid`);
  }

  const doLogin = () => {
    // do login logic
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="email" name="email" onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type="password" name="email" onChange={handleChange} />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default SignUpForm;
```

You also can try `useEffect`

```
const initialFormState = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
}

const SignUpForm = () => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialFormState);
  const [validationErrors, setValidationErrors] = useState<string>([]);

  const handleChange = () => {
    // handle the change implementation updating the formValues ...
  }

  //introduce useEffect here
  useEffect(() => {
     if (validationErrors.length > 0) {
      console.log('validation errors!!');
      return;
    }

    doLogin();
  }, [validationErrors]);

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    doValidationOnSubmit();
  };

  const doValidationOnSubmit = () => {
    Object.entries(formValues).forEach(([inputName, value]) => {
      if (formValues[inputName] === '') {
        setValidationErrors((oldValidationErrors) => [...oldValidationErrors, `${inputName} is not valid`]);
      }
    });
  }

  const doLogin = () => {
    // do login logic
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="email" name="email" onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type="password" name="email" onChange={handleChange} />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default SignUpForm;
```

If it does not work for your case, you can *delay* using the latest state with `setTimeout`. With this approach, it will put the task to get the latest state to the end of the call stack queue (you can check [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#late_timeouts))

```
const initialFormState = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
}

const SignUpForm = () => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialFormState);
  const [validationErrors, setValidationErrors] = useState<string>([]);

  const handleChange = () => {
    // handle the change implementation updating the formValues ...
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    doValidationOnSubmit();

    setTimeout(() => {
       if (validationErrors.length > 0) {
         console.log('validation errors!!');
         return;
      }

      doLogin();
    })
  };

  const doValidationOnSubmit = () => {
    Object.entries(formValues).forEach(([inputName, value]) => {
      if (formValues[inputName] === '') {
        setValidationErrors((oldValidationErrors) => [...oldValidationErrors, `${inputName} is not valid`]);
      }
    });
  }

  const doLogin = () => {
    // do login logic
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="email" name="email" onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type="password" name="email" onChange={handleChange} />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default SignUpForm;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. For the first case if I use useEffect in that way I will perform the login method as soon as I have no errors in the validstionErrors array, right? But in my case when the page is rendered the first time the validationErrors list is empty. More in general what should be a best practice for achieving immediate state update? Thank you again

Comment: Ah, I got your concern, I just updated my answer again for the first part. You can check it out. I think it's suitable for your case, @Dave

Comment: Thanks Nick, you did exactly what I already did for achieving my goal, I was thinking if there was a better way of doing this, but seems that it's the only way at the moment. Thank you for your help

Comment: actually, everything will be easier if we use class-based component. We can have callback in `this.setState(state, () => { //do something with the latest state })`, but nowadays, most of us are adapting with function-based components. That's kind of trade-off for us :( @Dave